# Hong Kong Visa: official translation of documents?

Tags: visa, hong-kong, translations

Applying for a Job Visa in Hong Kong, should I provide an official translation of all my french official documents required for the application (diplomas in particular) ? Nothing is indicated on the HK immigration website.

What I mean by official translation: in France there are official translators, registered at the government level, that provide translations of documents but they are extremely expensive (~40€/$ per diplomas). In the US the equivalent would be notarized translations.

Answer (score 2):

I just translated myself and that was enough. You might want to clarify with your HR or immigration representative who's handling your application. But from my knowledge and experience it was always sufficient enough to just have any kind of translation. All my friends and colleagues did the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Immigration Department G[uidebook for Professionals for Employment in Hong Kong](http://www.immd.gov.hk/pdforms/ID(E)991.pdf) (at the foot of page 13):

> **Important Notice**
>
> 2. Where a document is not in Chinese or English, it must be accompanied by a Chinese or English translation certified as a true translation by a sworn translator, court translator, authorised public translator, certified translator, expert translator, or official translator.